# Android app crashes when internet is turned off

Tags: android, android-wifi

My app crashes when there is no internet connection available, but works fine when connected to the internet through wifi or data connection.

Can someone tell me how I can add an exception to avoid the crash?

Below is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;   
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;  

    String[] mPlaceType=null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner 
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnFind;

        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);


        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());


        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Google Map
            mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                    onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   


                    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];


                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyAuoLlC1LnlbneuG8cZEo3NCFHEstk0vpE");


                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());


                }
            });

        }       

    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);                


                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();                

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }         


    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            

            // Clears all the existing markers 
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker. 
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);               

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);            

            }       

        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Below is the logcat log:

```
11-27 21:48:26.715: E/ActivityManager(242): ---wwd->startActivityLocked(14),packagename=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby,className=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby.MainActivity
11-27 21:48:26.831: E/FaceService(17156): -1--wwd->onReceive-action=com.android.tdc.stoppreview,packageName=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby,className=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby.MainActivity
11-27 21:48:26.912: E/FaceService(17156): -1--wwd->onReceive-action=com.android.tdc.stoppreview,packageName=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby,className=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby.MainActivity
11-27 21:48:27.633: E/samfan(17143): gestureActive=0
11-27 21:48:27.643: E/samfan(17143): gestureGallery=0
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10089 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10089 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:663)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:420)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4546)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
11-27 21:48:28.026: E/AndroidRuntime(17236):    ... 11 more
11-27 21:48:28.599: E/Launcher(8336): Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
11-27 21:48:28.603: E/Activity(8336): zbx The class is: com.android.phone
11-27 21:48:28.604: E/FaceService(17156): -1--wwd->onReceive-action=com.sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME,packageName=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby,className=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationnearby.MainActivity
```

Comment: Can you please post the error log and line number at which the error is being showed?

Comment: @JoelFernandes I have added the logcat log.

Comment: Have you added the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`??

Comment: @Naddy thank you, I didn't have that in the manifest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't have the android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in the manifest.

Comment: No problem, if it works make sure you accept the answer. Otherwise let me know and we can take a further look.

Comment: Hello there, i have the same problem but with downloading video using exoplayer download manager, i set all the permissions but still no result. if you know pls help me.